# close external application before closing the main application

Tags: c#, winforms, sccm

I am working on development of a plugin writing in c# winforms for an application.
I have set up a start action in debug. I have set start external program and it is starting that application.
In my winforms I have written code for a button click event which starts a new process say **notepad.exe**

Now the question is whenever I close that external application all the opened notepad which are invoked from this button click event should be closed automatically.

Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Diagnostics.Process to start process, like this:

```
Process proc=Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

And in Closing event you can use:

```
proc.Kill;
```

Also you can store just an id of your processes:

```
//arr is int array where stored your processes ids
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
{
    Process.GetProcessById(arr[i]).Kill();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I would agree with your answer. But my scenario is different. I need to close this notepad when my external application closes and I dont have source code of this external application. I am just running this application by specifying start external program in debug properties. so where would I use this stub in my plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I close Notepad when Calculator is closed:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("calc"))
        {
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.Exited += p_Exited;
        }
    }

    void p_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"))
        {
            p.CloseMainWindow();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but here I dont have the source code of that external application. So where should I write this stub ??

Comment: You said: `In my winforms I have written code for a button click event which starts a new process say notepad.exe` ...so put that code into the Form with that Button?  When the Form loads you wire up the Exited() event of the external application.  This doesn't involve code in the external application at all..